# BootStrap tagsinput with Spring MVC form

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to convert a spring form input text field to a field that converst text to tags, using https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/. But I am unable to bind this value to my model and pass it to the controller. Any ideas how I can use this plugin in a spring form? Should I instead submit the form through an ajax call instead?

I am stuck with this since 2 days and would appreciate any pointers to unblock myself.

Comment: Can you share some [minimal, complete, verifiable code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) examples of what you have tried already?

Comment: Please, next time provide a code that you have, otherwise you won't have an answer at all or the answers won't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says the following:

> Bootstrap Tags Input provides true multivalue support. Just use a  as your input element, and val() will return an array of the tag values. When submitting the form, an array of values will be sent with the request.

This means that on the server side you should be able to handle it in this way:

```
@PostMapping("/handle-tags")
public String handleTags(@RequestParam("tags") List<String> tags) {
    ...
}
```

Or by defining a similar field in the DTO object:

```
@PostMapping("/handle-tags")
public String handleTags(MyForm form) {
    ...
}
```

where `MyForm` looks like this:

```
public MyForm {
    private List<String> tags;
}
```

Note that name `tags` should match the `name` parameter of the `<input>` tag.